# remove backslash at every line

Tags: bash

I'm trying to clean a file from description, special characters and get only the ID column and the count column without the backslash. I was able to remove the description, but I want to remove the backslash, I used:

```
sed '/^{/d' GSM2580320_counts.txt | tr '\\' ' ' | grep -vE '^__' GSM2580320_counts.txt> GSM2580320_counts01.txt
cat GSM2580320_counts01.txt | head
```

This is the output:

```
ID              Count
ENSG00000005075 459\
ENSG00000005100 1766\
ENSG00000005102 10\
ENSG00000005108 14517\
ENSG00000005156 3101\
ENSG00000005175 867\
ENSG00000005187 6\
ENSG00000005189 307\
ENSG00000005194 1368\
ENSG00000005206 2429\
```

I tried:

```
sed 's/\\//g'
```

Also:

```
sed 's/\\/ /g'
```

But not luck!

tail of data:

```
ENSG00000285991 2\
ENSG00000285992 0\
ENSG00000285993 0\
ENSG00000285994 20\
__no_feature    7388512\
__ambiguous 1016493\
__too_low_aQual 0\
__not_aligned   2087327\
__alignment_not_unique  5970495\
}
```

head of data:

```
ENSG00000005075 459\
ENSG00000005100 1766\
ENSG00000005102 10\
ENSG00000005108 14517\
ENSG00000005156 3101\
ENSG00000005175 867\
ENSG00000005187 6\
ENSG00000005189 307\
ENSG00000005194 1368\
ENSG00000005206 2429\
```

Comment: `| grep -vE '^__' GSM2580320_counts.txt> GSM2580320_counts01.txt` - you're ignoring the piped data and instead re-reading the raw file.

Comment: I tried this but it is still not working  grep -vE '^__' GSM2580320_counts.txt | tr '\\' ' ' | sed '/^{/d' | > GSM2580320_counts01.txt
cat GSM2580320_counts01.txt @KenY-N

Comment: What's the correct syntax @KenY-N?

Comment: @user432797, if you could provide us samples of input and expected output then we could probably perform this task in a single command itself rather, kindly do provide samples in your question, thank you.

Comment: Delete `GSM2580320_counts.txt` altogether - `sed '/^{/d' GSM2580320_counts.txt | tr '\\' ' ' | grep -vE '^__' > GSM2580320_counts01.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to roll everything into a single `sed` script.

```sh
sed -e '/^{/d' -e '/^__/d' -e 's/\\//g' GSM2580320_counts.txt > GSM2580320_counts01.txt
```

If you only want to remove backslash at end of line, use `s/\\$//`

For anything more complicated, probably replace `sed` with Awk.